# Reloading one Top Div by choosing a link in a Bottom Div (which needs to behave independently)

Tags: iframe, html, reload

I hope you can help me with this one!

I have a filmsContents.php file with movies details (title, director, year) located as items of an array called $films.

It looks like this:

```
<?php

$films = array(
    'movieOne' => array(
            'title' => array(
                'en'=>'Movie ONE',
                'es'=>'PELICULA UNO'
                    ),
            'director' => 'John Doe 1',
            'year' => '2011'
            ),
    'movieTwo' => array(
            'title' => array(
                'en'=>'Movie TWO',
                'es'=>'PELICULA DOS'
                    ),
            'director' => 'John Doe 2',
            'year' => '2010'
            ),
    'movieThree' => array(
            'title' => array(
                'en'=>'Movie THREE',
                'es'=>'PELICULA TRES'
                    ),
            'director' => 'John Doe 3',
            'year' => '2009'
            ),
    'movieFour' => array(
            'title' => array(
                'en'=>'Movie Four',
                'es'=>'PELICULA CUATRO'
                    ),
            'director' => 'John Doe 4',
            'year' => '2008'
            ),
    'movieFive' => array(
            'title' => array(
                'en'=>'Movie FIVE',
                'es'=>'PELICULA CINCO'
                    ),
            'director' => 'John Doe 5',
            'year' => '2007'
            ),
    'movieSix' => array(
            'title' => array(
                'en'=>'Movie SIX',
                'es'=>'PELICULA SEIS'
                    ),
            'director' => 'John Doe 6',
            'year' => '2007'
            )

        );

?>
```

what I would like to do is:

To have a page with a Main top Div where details of one of the movies are displayed, and a bottom scrolling Div where I have the links for each movie to be displayed on the top Div.

I could do this perfectly BUT... When I have 15 movies on my bottom scrolling Div, and I click the last movie on the right, it loads the whole page, so the bottom scrolling Div doesn't stay in the same place where it was when I clicked on the link of the last movie, if not goes to the beginning of that bottom scrolling Div.

This is my films.php file:

```
<?php include_once("filmsContent.php");

@$film = $_REQUEST['title'];

?>

<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
    <head>


    </head>
<body>          


<?php


echo "<div class='content'>"; ?>

    <div class='films'>

    <?php echo $films[$film]['title']['en']."<br />";
          echo $films[$film]['director']."<br />";
          echo $films[$film]['year']."<br />";
    ?>

    </div>


    <div style='width: 200px;   height: 60px; overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden;'>

    <div style='width: 700px;'>

    <?php 

foreach($films as $film=>$attribute)
    {
    echo "<a href='?title=".$film."'>".$films[$film]['title']['en']."</a> | ";

    }
    ?>  
        </div>
        </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

What I wish is to have the Top Div reloaded with the info of the movie I choose every time, and only that Div, not the entire page, that way the bottom scrolling Div will behave independently of the Top Div.

I want to avoid Iframes or Objects. I believe I need to use JQuery, AJAX, but I don't know how to make it work. I've been searching for hours to find the solution for this and I had no luck.

Could you help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you need to use is some type of 'Carousel' jquery plugin ( google there are so many )

Here is one

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/infinite-carousel.html

here is some more

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/06/jquery-carousel.html

Comment: Thanks GX, the thing is the customer wants to avoid any special effects on the scrolling bottom div, it should be as simple as posible: one click on the link and the movie details are displayed with no special effects.